# Haskell: downpair :: (Monad m) => m (a, b) -> (m a, m b) implementation

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to implement function downpairs which takes monad of pairs and transform it into pair of monad

My current implementation is

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Maybe

downpair :: (Monad m) => m (a, b) -> (m a, m b)
downpair = ((return . fst =<<) &&& (return . snd =<<)) 

main = do
    print $ downpair $ Just ("Hello", "World")
```

Is there way to implement downpair in more compact maner?

PS Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(return . fst =<<)` can be replaced by `fmap fst`. Your definition then becomes

```
downpair = fmap fst &&& fmap snd
```